# How do I find the the third vertex of an isosceles triangle, if the vertex is on the y-axis?

Tags: geometry

$ABC$ is an isosceles triangle ($AB=AC$). We know that $A(5;9)$, $B(4;2)$ and $C$ lies on the $y$-axis. How to find $C$?

Answer (score 2):

Let the coordinates of $C$ be $(0,c)$, and then express the lengths of $AB$ and $AC$ by using the distance formula.

The distance formula:

> The distance between two points $(x_1,y_1)$ and $(x_2,y_2)$ is:
>   $$d=\sqrt{(x_1-x_2)^2+(y_1-y_2)^2}$$

Answer (score 1):

Since $C=(0,c)$ and
$$ AB^2 = (5-4)^2+(9-2)^2 = 50, $$
$$ AC^2 = 5^2+(9-c)^2 = 25+(9-c)^2, $$
we must have $|9-c|=5$, so the solutions are $\color{red}{c=4}$ and $\color{red}{c=14}$.

Answer (score 0):

Since $C=(0,c)$ The midpoint of $BC$ is $P=(2,1+{c\over 2})$ Now $AP$ is perpendicular to $BC$  so, $${2-c\over 4-0}\cdot {9-(1+{c\over 2})\over 5-2}=-1$$

Solve and you will get $c=4 $ OR $14$